# Mongoose not Conecting to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm making a GridView in Node.js, But, It's Not connecting to Mongoose and Creating the DB. When I write

> show dbs

In my Mongo Shell Then I don't get my Database Created.

This is my Code

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const app = express();
const port = 80;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/griData", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, (err)=> {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);

app.get("/", (req, res)=> {
    res.render("main");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: any console output?

Comment: 2 <<That is my Status Code for Connection that means Connecting then also not creating database as it does automatically>>
 App listening at localhost:80

Answer (score 1):

The database will be created when you will add a first document in the collection automatically.

Comment: Mongooose connects by itself I think. Thank you